# Grabbing specific rows and export those to another csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

What i am trying to do here, grabbing specific rows by name. And my csv data table is horizontal. Not vertical, you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL1dD.jpg).
Yellow part is headers.

The sample is like below.

```
---
Row 1 DATA DATA DATA
---
Row 2 YSS  YDD   GGS
---
Row 3 DATA DATA DATA
---
Row 4 DATA DATA DATA
---
```

Parse row 2, 3, 4 and then export it to another new.csv file. Tricky part is. After exporting the another file. I want to change row 2's data　names.

new.csv sample is:

```
Row 2 YSS  YDD  GGS
---
Row 3 DATA DATA DATA
---
Row 4 DATA DATA DATA
---
```

So trying to give names to Row 2's data. For example if YSS then make YSS -> Google or if it's YDD then make it Yahoo. Export is a new2.csv again, is like:

```
Row 2 Google  Yahoo  Facebook
---
Row 3 DATA    DATA   DATA
---
Row 4 DATA    DATA   DATA
---
```

I start with this but I can't get what want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("datas.csv", index_col=0)
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.iloc[0].isnull()]._data)
df_out = df.loc['利用額(Fee抜き)','クライアント名','媒体'] 

print(df_out)
```

> KeyError: 'the label [クライアント名] is not in the [columns]'

Comment: Can you please share code that you have tried.

Comment: I added what I tried but, I can't get what I want. couldn't manage to grab header and the header's data... @MayankBansal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you may need something like this:

Considering the `df` looks like :

```
    0       1       2       3
0   Row 2   YSS     YDD     GGS
1   Row 3   DATA    DATA    DATA
2   Row 4   DATA    DATA    DATA

d = {'YSS':'Google','YDD':'Yahoo','GGS':'Facebook'}
df.T.loc[1:,0] = df.T.loc[1:,0].map(d)
>>df

    0       1       2       3
0   Row 2   Google  Yahoo   Facebook
1   Row 3   DATA    DATA    DATA
2   Row 4   DATA    DATA    DATA
```

If `Row 2` is not a column instead an index just do:

```
df.loc['Row 2'] = df.loc['Row 2'].map(d)
>>df

        1       2       3
0           
Row 2   Google  Yahoo   Facebook
Row 3   DATA    DATA    DATA
Row 4   DATA    DATA    DATA
```

Comment: The problem is I can't grab the horizontal header's and rows... could you please, explain to me how can I grab 2,3,4 too

Comment: @Barbie : is `Row 2` , `Row 3` etc is an index or a column? Also if you can tell me what are the headers? I read the file as `pd.csv('file.csv',header=None)` for the example

Comment: @Barbie , i have used a transpose to access the labels, you can try that too, also try putting header=None

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tWkYvrk you can see. How can it's columns i think? :) I don't know. the header rows I want is. "クライアント名" and "媒体" and this "利用額(Fee抜き)"

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("datas.csv", index_col=0,  header=None)` I tried it like this but still same error pops up. I can't even get the rows.... this is so annoying...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186754/discussion-between-barbie-and-anky-91).